# How to open .xsn file programatically from OutLook Add-in code

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have requirement to open .xsn file with InfoPath from outlook plugin code. Basically I have list of .xsn file stored in some location. Now I need to open that .xsn file with InfoPath from OutLook add-in code. Please guide me how to achieve this. Give me list of api/classes documentation location so I can read and proceed further. Please note that I am not developing add-in for InfoPath, but I am developing add-in for outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer from link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa943009.aspx  . I have answered my own question so it may be helpful to others. I didn't check above link on InfoPath document page, but finally I got it :-)